# How to read specific columns in the csv file?

Tags: python, database, csv

I have lots of live data coming from sensor. Currently, I stored the data in a csv file as following:

```
0  2  1  437   464  385  171    0:44:4   dog.jpg
1  1  3  452   254  444  525    0:56:2   cat.jpg
2  3  2  552   525  785  522    0:52:8   car.jpg
3  8  4  552   525  233  555    0:52:8   car.jpg
4  7  5  552   525  433  522    1:52:8   phone.jpg
5  9  3  552   525  555  522    1:52:8   car.jpg
6  6  6  444   392  111  232    1:43:4   dog.jpg
7  1  1  234   322  191  112    1:43:4   dog.jpg
.
.
```

.
.

Third column has numbers between 1 to 6. I want to read information of columns #4 and #5 for  all the rows that have number 2 and 5 in the third columns. I also want to write them in another csv file line by line every 2 second, one line at the time.
I do so because I have another code which would go through the data and read the data from there. I was wondering how could I write the information for the lines that have 3 and 5 in their 3rd column? Please advise!

for example:

```
2  552   525  
5  552   525  
......
......
.....
```

.

```
import csv

with open('newfilename.csv', 'w') as f2:
    with open('mydata.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)  # no conversion to list
        header = next(reader)  # get first line
        for row in reader:  # continue to read one line per loop

            if row[5] == 2 & 5:
```

Comment: I think that's `row[2]` (the third row) and you could do `if row[2] in (2, 5)`

Comment: Thanks, I also need to write the lines every 2 seconds, how could I write them one by one? instead of all at once

Comment: @Happypumpkinpm Please let me know if my answer helps or not!

Comment: Add time.sleep(2) after each write.

Comment: The issue is when I use time.sleep(2)  the output gets empty. Please look at oda's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third column has index 2 so you should be checking if `row[2]` is one of `'2'` or `'5'`. I have done this by defining the set `select = {'2', '5'}` and checking if `row[2] in select`.

I don't see what you are using `header` for but I assume you have more code that processes `header` somewhere. If you don't need `header` and just want to skip the first line, just do `next(reader)` without assigning it to `header` but I have kept `header` in my code under the assumption you use it later.

We can use `time.sleep(2)` from the `time` module to help us write a row every 2 seconds.

Below, `"in.txt"` is the csv file containing the sample input you provided and `"out.txt"` is the file we write to.

**Code**

```
import csv
import time

select = {'2', '5'}
with open("in.txt") as f_in, open("out.txt", "w") as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    header = next(reader)    
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] in select:
            print(f"Writing {row[2:5]} at {time.time()}")
            writer.writerow(row[2:5])
            # f_out.flush() may need to be run here
            time.sleep(2)
```

**Output**

```
Writing ['2', '552', '525'] at 1650526118.9760585
Writing ['5', '552', '525'] at 1650526120.9763758
```

`"out.txt"`

```
2,552,525
5,552,525
```

**Input**

`"in.txt"`

```
0,2,1,437,464,385,171,0:44:4,dog.jpg
1,1,3,452,254,444,525,0:56:2,cat.jpg
2,3,2,552,525,785,522,0:52:8,car.jpg
3,8,4,552,525,233,555,0:52:8,car.jpg
4,7,5,552,525,433,522,1:52:8,phone.jpg
5,9,3,552,525,555,522,1:52:8,car.jpg
6,6,6,444,392,111,232,1:43:4,dog.jpg
7,1,1,234,322,191,112,1:43:4,dog.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you @oda, the time.sleep(2) does not let the outputs to be written in the out.txt. after running the code, it is empty. I wonder how to fix that? When I remove time.sleep the output all are written at once, but when I include time.sleep the txt output is empty.

Comment: That's strange. It works perfectly on my side. May I ask what you are using to run the code? Do you have other processes / threads running simultaneously? Can you try running the script on the command line with switch `-u`?

Comment: I use command line to run the code. I have anaconda prompt. It prints everty 2 second over console, but does not update the text file, are you sure "out.txt" is not empty? because mine is empty after running the code.

Comment: Yes. I first made `out.txt` empty. After running the code it is no longer empty.

Comment: Try running `f_out.flush()` just above `time.sleep(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd just need to change your if statement to be able to get the rows you want.

for example:

```
import csv

with open('newfilename.csv', 'w') as f2:
    with open('mydata.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)  # no conversion to list
        header = next(reader)  # get first line
        for row in reader:  # continue to read one line per loop

            if row[5] in [2,5]:
```

inside the if, you'll get the rows that have 2 or 5

Comment: Thank you, could you please also tell how to complete the part that writes into csv? I need to write it line by line every 2 seconds.