# How can i write a python code to read the “cities.csv” file . Print the contents of Columns named “LatM”,”NS” ,”LonM” and “EW” where “State” is “CA”?

Tags: python, django

this is mt cities.csv file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwj1Y.png)

```
LatD,LatM,LatS,NS,LonD,LonM,LonS,EW,City,State
41,5,59,N,80,39,0,W,Youngstown, OH
42,52,48,N,97,23,23,W,Yankton, SD
46,35,59,N,120,30,36,W,Yakima, WA
42,16,12,N,71,48,0,W,Worcester, MA
43,37,48,N,89,46,11,W,Wisconsin Dells, WI
36,5,59,N,80,15,0,W,Winston-Salem, NC
49,52,48,N,97,9,0,W,Winnipeg, MB
39,11,23,N,78,9,36,W,Winchester, VA
34,14,24,N,77,55,11,W,Wilmington, NC
39,45,0,N,75,33,0,W,Wilmington, DE
48,9,0,N,103,37,12,W,Williston, ND
41,15,0,N,77,0,0,W,Williamsport, PA
37,40,48,N,82,16,47,W,Williamson, WV
33,54,0,N,98,29,23,W,Wichita Falls, TX
37,41,23,N,97,20,23,W,Wichita, KS
40,4,11,N,80,43,12,W,Wheeling, WV
26,43,11,N,80,3,0,W,West Palm Beach, FL
47,25,11,N,120,19,11,W,Wenatchee, WA
41,25,11,N,122,23,23,W,Weed, CA
31,13,11,N,82,20,59,W,Waycross, GA
44,57,35,N,89,38,23,W,Wausau, WI
42,21,36,N,87,49,48,W,Waukegan, IL
44,54,0,N,97,6,36,W,Watertown, SD
43,58,47,N,75,55,11,W,Watertown, NY
42,30,0,N,92,20,23,W,Waterloo, IA
41,32,59,N,73,3,0,W,Waterbury, CT
38,53,23,N,77,1,47,W,Washington, DC
41,50,59,N,79,8,23,W,Warren, PA
46,4,11,N,118,19,48,W,Walla Walla, WA
31,32,59,N,97,8,23,W,Waco, TX
38,40,48,N,87,31,47,W,Vincennes, IN
28,48,35,N,97,0,36,W,Victoria, TX
32,20,59,N,90,52,47,W,Vicksburg, MS
49,16,12,N,123,7,12,W,Vancouver, BC
46,55,11,N,98,0,36,W,Valley City, ND
30,49,47,N,83,16,47,W,Valdosta, GA
43,6,36,N,75,13,48,W,Utica, NY
39,54,0,N,79,43,48,W,Uniontown, PA
32,20,59,N,95,18,0,W,Tyler, TX
42,33,36,N,114,28,12,W,Twin Falls, ID
33,12,35,N,87,34,11,W,Tuscaloosa, AL
34,15,35,N,88,42,35,W,Tupelo, MS
36,9,35,N,95,54,36,W,Tulsa, OK
32,13,12,N,110,58,12,W,Tucson, AZ
37,10,11,N,104,30,36,W,Trinidad, CO
40,13,47,N,74,46,11,W,Trenton, NJ
44,45,35,N,85,37,47,W,Traverse City, MI
43,39,0,N,79,22,47,W,Toronto, ON
39,2,59,N,95,40,11,W,Topeka, KS
41,39,0,N,83,32,24,W,Toledo, OH
33,25,48,N,94,3,0,W,Texarkana, TX
39,28,12,N,87,24,36,W,Terre Haute, IN
27,57,0,N,82,26,59,W,Tampa, FL
30,27,0,N,84,16,47,W,Tallahassee, FL
47,14,24,N,122,25,48,W,Tacoma, WA
43,2,59,N,76,9,0,W,Syracuse, NY
32,35,59,N,82,20,23,W,Swainsboro, GA
33,55,11,N,80,20,59,W,Sumter, SC
40,59,24,N,75,11,24,W,Stroudsburg, PA
37,57,35,N,121,17,24,W,Stockton, CA
44,31,12,N,89,34,11,W,Stevens Point, WI
40,21,36,N,80,37,12,W,Steubenville, OH
40,37,11,N,103,13,12,W,Sterling, CO
38,9,0,N,79,4,11,W,Staunton, VA
39,55,11,N,83,48,35,W,Springfield, OH
37,13,12,N,93,17,24,W,Springfield, MO
42,5,59,N,72,35,23,W,Springfield, MA
39,47,59,N,89,39,0,W,Springfield, IL
47,40,11,N,117,24,36,W,Spokane, WA
41,40,48,N,86,15,0,W,South Bend, IN
43,32,24,N,96,43,48,W,Sioux Falls, SD
42,29,24,N,96,23,23,W,Sioux City, IA
32,30,35,N,93,45,0,W,Shreveport, LA
33,38,23,N,96,36,36,W,Sherman, TX
44,47,59,N,106,57,35,W,Sheridan, WY
35,13,47,N,96,40,48,W,Seminole, OK
32,25,11,N,87,1,11,W,Selma, AL
38,42,35,N,93,13,48,W,Sedalia, MO
47,35,59,N,122,19,48,W,Seattle, WA
41,24,35,N,75,40,11,W,Scranton, PA
41,52,11,N,103,39,36,W,Scottsbluff, NB
42,49,11,N,73,56,59,W,Schenectady, NY
32,4,48,N,81,5,23,W,Savannah, GA
46,29,24,N,84,20,59,W,Sault Sainte Marie, MI
27,20,24,N,82,31,47,W,Sarasota, FL
38,26,23,N,122,43,12,W,Santa Rosa, CA
35,40,48,N,105,56,59,W,Santa Fe, NM
34,25,11,N,119,41,59,W,Santa Barbara, CA
33,45,35,N,117,52,12,W,Santa Ana, CA
37,20,24,N,121,52,47,W,San Jose, CA
37,46,47,N,122,25,11,W,San Francisco, CA
41,27,0,N,82,42,35,W,Sandusky, OH
32,42,35,N,117,9,0,W,San Diego, CA
34,6,36,N,117,18,35,W,San Bernardino, CA
29,25,12,N,98,30,0,W,San Antonio, TX
31,27,35,N,100,26,24,W,San Angelo, TX
40,45,35,N,111,52,47,W,Salt Lake City, UT
38,22,11,N,75,35,59,W,Salisbury, MD
36,40,11,N,121,39,0,W,Salinas, CA
38,50,24,N,97,36,36,W,Salina, KS
38,31,47,N,106,0,0,W,Salida, CO
44,56,23,N,123,1,47,W,Salem, OR
44,57,0,N,93,5,59,W,Saint Paul, MN
38,37,11,N,90,11,24,W,Saint Louis, MO
39,46,12,N,94,50,23,W,Saint Joseph, MO
42,5,59,N,86,28,48,W,Saint Joseph, MI
44,25,11,N,72,1,11,W,Saint Johnsbury, VT
45,34,11,N,94,10,11,W,Saint Cloud, MN
29,53,23,N,81,19,11,W,Saint Augustine, FL
43,25,48,N,83,56,24,W,Saginaw, MI
38,35,24,N,121,29,23,W,Sacramento, CA
43,36,36,N,72,58,12,W,Rutland, VT
33,24,0,N,104,31,47,W,Roswell, NM
35,56,23,N,77,48,0,W,Rocky Mount, NC
41,35,24,N,109,13,48,W,Rock Springs, WY
42,16,12,N,89,5,59,W,Rockford, IL
43,9,35,N,77,36,36,W,Rochester, NY
44,1,12,N,92,27,35,W,Rochester, MN
37,16,12,N,79,56,24,W,Roanoke, VA
37,32,24,N,77,26,59,W,Richmond, VA
39,49,48,N,84,53,23,W,Richmond, IN
38,46,12,N,112,5,23,W,Richfield, UT
45,38,23,N,89,25,11,W,Rhinelander, WI
39,31,12,N,119,48,35,W,Reno, NV
50,25,11,N,104,39,0,W,Regina, SA
40,10,48,N,122,14,23,W,Red Bluff, CA
40,19,48,N,75,55,48,W,Reading, PA
41,9,35,N,81,14,23,W,Ravenna, OH
```

```py
import csv

with open('cities.csv', 'r') as file:                                                                   
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)                                                                       
    for row in reader:
        print(row['LatM'],row['NS'],row['LonM'],row['EW'],row['State'])          
        if row['State']=="CA": 
         print(row['LatM'],row['NS'],row['LonM'],row['EW'],row['State'])
```

if condition is not working

Comment: try `csv.DictReader(file)` rather than `csv.reader(file)`

Comment: Add inside the *for* loop `if row["State"] == "CA":`, and move the *print* line under it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) might help you understand the CSV module in python, while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949119/how-to-read-specific-columns-in-the-csv-file) might help more specifically with what you are asking. In all, you'll need the CSV package, a for-loop, and some if-statements.

Comment: condition is not working properly

Comment: Please paste the data as the actual CSV **text** not an image so it can be copied and used for testing.

Comment: i added the content

Comment: The text in your CSV file has something that looks like a space before the state codes.  What happens if change your test to `==" CA"`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may want to use `cvs.DictReader`. The following code reads the element under the `"LatD"` column, one row at a time:

```
import csv                                                                                              
                                                                                                        
with open('cities.csv', 'r') as file:                                                                   
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)                                                                       
    for row in reader:                                                                                  
        print(row['LatD'])
```

Note, however, that, for other columns, you may run into issues of undefined keys in the `reader` object. This is because some of the labels in the header contain an extra pair of quoting signs. You should clean these if you can help it.

Provided that the header contains valid keys, if you need to print specific columns, try

```
with open('cities.csv', 'r') as file:                                                                   
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)                                                                       
    selected = ["LatD"]                                                                                 
    for row in reader:                                                                                  
        print([elem for key, elem in row.items() if key in selected])
```

Comment: it is printing LatD but how can we print'LatD these four rows together where state=CA','NS','LonM','EW'

Comment: Check the EDIT to my answer. Add the columns you need to `selected`. Remember: you need valid keys in the file's header.